# Missing number treated as zero and Illegal unit of measure when using subfigure

Tags: subfloats

I am trying to put two figures side by side and keep getting these two errors:

```
Missing number treated as zero.
Illegal unit of measure.
```

The only way I don't get them is if I comment the `{0.5\textwidth}`. However if I comment it the figures stay one under the other.

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{Figuras/SICAPI2014.eps}
        \caption{SICAPI}
        \label{fig.SICAPI}
    \end{subfigure}%

\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{Figuras/painel_sicapi.eps}
    \caption{Painel de operação}
    \label{fig.painel_sicapi}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Planta Piloto SICAPI}
\label{fig.sicapi}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Just remove the blank line between the `subfigure`environments and replace it with `\quad`, for instance.

Comment: The error disappearing when you remove `{0.5\textwidth}` means you're loading the package `subfigure` (which has been deprecated for 15 years) instead of `subcaption`. The blank line between the two `subfigure` environments should be removed. Voting for closure as “unclear”.

Answer (score 1):

As @Bernard say in his comment, blank lines between sub figures tell to LaTeX: "Put them each in own line". In similar cases I wrote as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}

    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering% center subfigures in float
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}
        \caption{SICAPI}
        \label{fig.SICAPI}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfil% accomodate space between sub figures
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}
    \caption{Painel de operação}
    \label{fig.painel_sicapi}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{Planta Piloto SICAPI}
    \label{fig.sicapi}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

I didn't check where arise errors about which you complain. In above example they are not presented. How to use `subfigure` se package documentation or brief description in Wikibooks: [LaTeX/Floats, Figures and Captions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions).