# subfigure subcaption in centre

Tags: subcaption

Please suggest me a way to put subfigures sub-caption which can be placed in the centre. For eg. there is a figure containing 8 subfigures, in a 4*2 manner, means each of four-row contains 2 subfigures. I want to have common subfigure caption for each of these 2 figures for every row. means in total, 4 subfigure sub-caption, and one main caption.

```
     \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

      \usepackage{graphicx}
      \usepackage{   When I changed subfigure}
     \usepackage{ to sub float,caption}

     \begin{document}
     \begin{ another figure}
      \centering
              \subfigure[XYZ Dataset]\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth,height=3.5cm]
 {plots/butter10template gave errors.jpg}}\hfil
             \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth,height=3.5cm]{plots/butter10.jpg}} 
           \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth,height=3.5cm]       \[![enter image description here][1]][1]begin{plots/butter10.jpg}figure*}\hfil
      \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth,height=3.5cm]{plots/butter10.jpg}}       \centering
           \subfigure[]      {\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth49\textwidth,height=3height=0.5cm]16\textwidth]{plotspdf_plots/butter10low_10.jpgpdf}}\hfil
              \subfigure[]       {\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth49\textwidth,height=3height=0.5cm]16\textwidth]{plotspdf_plots/butter10full_10.jpgpdf}}  
               \subfigure[]       {\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth49\textwidth,height=3height=0.5cm]16\textwidth]{plotspdf_plots/butter10low_50.jpgpdf}}\hfil
         \subfigure[]      
 
 {\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth49textwidth,height=3height=0.5cm]16\textwidth]{plotspdf_plots/butter10full_50.jpgpdf}}  
           \caption{abcd}\label{fig:abcd}
           \end{figure}
            \end{documentfigure*}
```

This code outputs an image as shown in attached figPlease help me to resolve this issue. But I dont want subfigure label for each of 8 figures, as a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h, rather I want subfigure label (a) placed at centre commonly for first two figures. seconf subfigure (b) for second row and so on.

This code outputs an image as shown in attached fig. But I don'tI want subfigure label for each of 8 figures, as4 subplots a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h, rather I want subfigure label (a) placed at centre commonly for first two figures. second subfigure (b) for second row and so on.d

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us, what you try so far (in form of small complete document with your figure)! Caption of sub figures are usually centered below figures. As an example see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248675/

Comment: Welcome Dipti, please, it is very helpful (and also kind!), when you provide a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example), so that people may better understand your question and give you an answer more quickly by modifying your code.

Comment: you completely change your question and by this nullify received answer. If you have new problem, please ask new question! Please revert your question to the version before this edit.

Comment: This web site appears to be having a hard time with some of your 16 bit characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `subfigure` is obsolete package, use `subfloat` instead of it
- you can put two images in one `subfloat`:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.48\linewidth,height=3.5cm} % common settings for images sizes 
\subfloat[]
{
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}    %{plots/butter10.jpg}
\hfill
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
}

\subfloat[]
{
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}    
\hfill
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
}

\subfloat[]
{
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}    
\hfill
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
}

\subfloat[]
{
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}    
\hfill
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
}
  \caption{abcd}
\label{fig:abcd}
   \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks it worked for me...

Comment: @DiptiMishra, than you can up-vote answer and even accept it (by clicking on up-pen ad check mark at top left side of the answer)  :-)