# How do I justify the text using subcaptions in the attached code?

Tags: captions, subfloats, revtex, subfig, justification

I am using revtex4-2 formatting, and have 2 columns. I would like to have 2x2 subfigure, each labeled by a different alphabet. And I want the caption to be justified. However, the attached code produces a centered text. How do I rectify this?

I know someone suggested using subfloat instead ([subfigure subcaption in centre](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542896/subfigure-subcaption-in-centre)). However, I am not able to label the two side-by-side figures separately using subfloat.

```
\documentclass[%
reprint,
superscriptaddress,
amsmath,amssymb,
aps,
pra,
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\preprint{APS/123-QED}

\title{Some Title}

\author{First author}
\affiliation{Place 1} 
\author{Second author}
\email{email2@email.com}
\affiliation{Place 1}
\affiliation{Place 2}

\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\blindtext

    \begin{figure}[t]   
       \includegraphics[width=0.95 \linewidth]{Figures/Aperture_image.jpg}
       \caption{\blindtext}
       \label{Fig:Model}
    \end{figure}

\blindtext 

\blindtext

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures_7/S0_Ex.eps}
        \caption{} \label{fig:7deg:a}
    \end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures_7/S0_Th.eps}
        \caption{} \label{fig:7deg:b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \medskip
    \begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures_7/Stokes_full_Ex.eps}
        \caption{} \label{fig:7deg:c}
    \end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures_7/Stokes_full_Th.eps}
        \caption{} \label{fig:7deg:d}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \caption{\blindtext} \label{fig:7deg}
\end{figure}

\blindtext 

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: If this is for publication, do not mess with the caption in any way.  The reason it is hard to change is because they don't want any changes.

Comment: @John Kormylo I checked other articles from the journal. The captions are supposed to be justified and not centered. Apparently, we should not use the `subcaption` package along `revtex4-2`, as was mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a warning, namely

```
Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package),
(caption)                standard defaults will be used.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

The `caption` package should not be used with `revtex4-2`.

You can use `subfig`, though.

```
\documentclass[
  reprint,
  superscriptaddress,
  amsmath,amssymb,
  aps,
  pra,
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\preprint{APS/123-QED}

\title{Some Title}

\author{First author}
\affiliation{Place 1} 
\author{Second author}
\email{email2@email.com}
\affiliation{Place 1}
\affiliation{Place 2}

\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\blindtext
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[t]   

\includegraphics[width=0.95\columnwidth]{Figures/Aperture_image.jpg}
\caption{\blindtext}
\label{Fig:Model}

\end{figure}

\blindtext 

\blindtext

\blindtext

\begin{figure}

\subfloat[\label{fig:7deg:a}]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{Figures_7/S0_Ex.eps}%
}\hspace*{\fill}%
\subfloat[\label{fig:7deg:b}]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{Figures_7/S0_Th.eps}%
}

\medskip

\subfloat[\label{fig:7deg:c}]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{Figures_7/Stokes_full_Ex.eps}%
}\hspace*{\fill}%
\subfloat[\label{fig:7deg:d}]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{Figures_7/Stokes_full_Th.eps}%
}
    
\caption{\blindtext} \label{fig:7deg}
\end{figure}

\blindtext 
\blindtext
\blindtext 
\blindtext
\blindtext 
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This works.