# The best way for putting pictures Side by side

Tags: subfloats, subcaption, subfig

I read similar questions and answers but unfortunately, I couldn't fix it.

1. I use `subcaption`  package;
2. I know the `subfigure` is relatively old. I try to use subfig environment but I was not succeeded.
   3(what is the best solution in this situation
3. Also, this code was working without any problem yesterday. I really appreciate any help in advance.
4. I use aip sample template '`revtex4-2` 'and I do not know what is the best package for it

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,twocolumn,floatfix,footinbib,notitlepage,superscriptaddress,groupaddress,subcaption,caption,showpacs]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx,graphics,times,bm,bbm,bbold,amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,dsfont,hyperref,mathrsfs,color,cancel}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}
    \preprint{AIP/123-QED}  
    \begin{figure*}\label{fig3ab}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{20mm}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{fig1}%
            \caption{}%
            \label{subfig3a}%
        \end{subfigure}\hfill%
        \begin{subfigure}{20mm}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{fig2}%
            \caption{}%
            \label{subfig3b}%
        \end{subfigure}\hfill%
        \caption{}
    \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

many thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not put my code between two marks( sometimes it happens to me

Comment: I put the code in a code block. The easiest way to do that is to use markdown `\`\`\`` (three backticks) on the line before the code and `\`\`\`` on the line afterwards.

Comment: Thank you very much @frabjous

Comment: The kind of code you're using is only compatible with the `subcaption` package. Take out the `subfigure` package and put in `subcaption` and it works fine as far as I can tell, though you should rearrange your packages and put `hyperref` at the end. (I'd avoid loading them all with the same command like like that; it makes it hard to make changes. You might also want to go bigger than 20mm.) If subcaption isn't working for you, explain how not.

Comment: many thanks @frabjous. I did your suggestions ( as others had proposed) but I got this error : Environment subfigure undefined. \begin{subfigure}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `revtex4-2` use the package `subfig`

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,twocolumn,floatfix,footinbib,notitlepage,superscriptaddress,groupaddres,showpacs]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx,graphics,times,bm,bbm,bbold,amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,dsfont,hyperref,mathrsfs,color,cancel}

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<


\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
 \preprint{AIP/123-QED}         
    
1.  \kant[1-2]
    
    \begin{figure}[ht!]
        
        \subfloat[\label{subfig3a}]{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth]{example-image}%
        }\hfill
        \subfloat[\label{subfig3b}]{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth]{example-image}%
        }\hfill         
        \caption{A caption of the figure}\label{fig:one}            
        \end{figure}
        
2.  \kant[2-4]  
    
\end{document}
```

[image: a]

See for example [using subcaptions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/620213/161015) (not compatible with `revtex4-2`)

Comment: I used subfig without {caption=fulse} and I didnt get any results. Very thanks. you save my day!! I really appreciate

Comment: Thank you @Simon Dispa for your considration